# Multitouch in Android on image

Tags: android, image, button

I've image as a button in Android and there are 6 Image buttons and now I want to have mulitouch on that 6 buttons

Any suggestion how to do that in Android?
Can u give me link bcoz I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to listen to touch events and to do some actions according to the button touched.